# Detecting 3G/wifi connection using only IP

Tags: parsing, networking, mobile, ip, 3g

I've got an old connection log to a website which contains the IP addresses, the user agent string and the timestamp.
I want to know how many of them used 3G to access a website as I suspect there is a latency issue.

Now I know that I can use some code to have this info directly from the user.

But I still want to process this old log using only IP addresses even if it is only for one ISP.

I thought I could do that by finding a list of the subnets used for 3g.

Do you think it can be done?
Otherwise, what do you suggest?

Hope you can help.
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to lookup every IP using "whois" services, if the ISP listed is a phone carrier only, you can be certain the connection was made by a mobile connection.

This is not a total solution, but it might give you enough information.

Now, to find a service which will allow you to make all the requests required, might be another matter.